# postgresql ssh keyboard-interactive authentification

Tags: remote-access, ssh-tunnel, postgresql-10, postico

I installed postgresql on a Windows Server 2007 and created a database in there.
As long as I work on local (localhost) there is no problem.
Now i want to remote access the created databases on my Mac using Postico.

I input the credentials and get the following error:
[image: Doesn't accept keyboard-interactive authentification but requires keyboard-interactive authentification.]

Can anyone tell me where I can solve this problem ?

Here is some follow-up info:

- my pg_hba.conf already has the following line:

`host    all    all    0.0.0.0/0    md5`

- my postgresql.conf has:

`listen_addresses = "*"` and `#ssl = off` (not sure if I have to turn it on).

- finally, here is a screenshot of the credentials:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

The options of the pg_hba.conf & postgresql.conf were OK.

However newbies like me might not know the following:

- Windows servers don't allow SSH natively - freeSSH helps with this
- The SSH host is the machine you are trying to connect to, and thus, the SSH user is the user of the SSH connection, not the database user.

Last little comment :

While this seems natural to most users of this platform, I found this information to be quite hard to find on google for pgsql, especially since it is so basic (try to find the difference between Host and SSH host assuming you know nothing about it). 
There are hardly any tutorials as to how to connect to a distant server using non-proprietary software without any codelines (as I don't understand DOS and terminal commands, i prefer not to use them).

It might be a good idea for someone with better understanding of the process to create a beginner tutorial on how to set up a connection to a database within a small company.

In case someone feels generous ... ;-)